# Join two tables into one by adding data of all tables sequentially

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I am facing an issue in joining three tables with different data.
Suppose I am having **table1** and **table2** like :

```
table1 :     table2:
ID1         ID2
-----        ----- 
1            102
2            103
```

I need to join these two tables into **table3** as :

```
table3
------
ID1    ID2
---    ---
1      102
2      103
```

I am applying cross join in table1 and table2 but i am gettng:

```
table3 :
ID1   ID2
---   ---
1     102
2     102
1     103 
2     103
```

Comment: How do you know that the row `Table1.ID1 1` matches the row `Table2.ID1 102`? Is it just the first row of one matches the first row of next when ordered by ID?

Comment: If you assume that just the row number will be how the engine should join those tables, then you need to specify that. 
You will need to create a number for each row on each table and then join them on that new column.

The cross join is supposed to combine every column of the first one with ever column of the second one, it's the Cartesian product of both tables.

The number can be created easily using ROW_NUMBER() function in SQL. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

Comment: yes, i want to match the first row of one to be matched with first row of second. @BeanFrog

Comment: Add one row to table2, and adjust the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply ordering by ID for each table, and then matching the first row with the first row - the following should work.

```
Select T1.ID1
     , T2.ID2
from (Select ID1, row_number() over (order by ID1) rownum from Table1) T1
inner join (Select ID2, row_number() over (order by ID2) rownum from Table2) T2
    on T1.rownum = T2.rownum
```

It create a subquery for each table with a row number, and then inner joins on the row number.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ID`'s are not always in sequential form then use this:

```
SELECT t1.ID1, T2.ID2
FROM (SELECT ID1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn FROM table1 ) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn FROM table2) t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```